# Proper way to store authentication in a Phonegap application

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

Let's say i have a phonegap application connecting to a web service to validate login credentials. Once authenticated, i want to have persistent authentication just like a standard web app that stores a cookies in a browser.

What are the guidelines for these? With security, reliability and standards are considered.

Please don't make this as a "native app vs html5 wrapped app " debate.

I appreciate all logical answers. Thank  you.

Comment: without https your in the "poor-mans-rsa land", have you considered openid, google authentication etc?

Comment: i've considered Facebook and Twitter API for authentication. It's a commercial application, so it needs to link to the popular social media sites

Answer (score 0):

is this an issue of generating authentication or storing it?

To generate, since you can't use UDID anymore, keep FB or twitter id is fine.
To store, you can write to UserDefaults or to an actual file (there was localStorage but it's currently unreliable).

Comment: can i keep them in a generated database?